# Convert this string to datetime

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Convert uncommon date format to timestamp in most efficient manner possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843423/php-convert-uncommon-date-format-to-timestamp-in-most-efficient-manner-possible)

How to convert this string to datetime format?
06/Oct/2011:19:00:02

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$s = '06/Oct/2011:19:00:02';

$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y:H:i:s', $s);
$date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: I think you mean `m` not `M`.

Comment: @Wobbles Nice spotted

Comment: It should be `M` (or `F`) as stated in the official documentation. @NamGVU please, do not edit greatly accepted answer, if you are not willing to retest the code by yourself. If your MWE yields output other then suggested by official maintainer, please consult it in separate thread or so.

Comment: > o not edit greatly accepted answer 
I don't think so @TomiL - things change thru time

Answer (score 34):

The Problem is with your code formatting,

inorder to use `strtotime()` You should replace `'06/Oct/2011:19:00:02'` with `06/10/2011 19:00:02` and `date('d/M/Y:H:i:s', $date);` with `date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date);`. Note the spaces in between.

So the final code looks like this

```
$s = '06/10/2011 19:00:02';
$date = strtotime($s);
echo date('d/M/Y H:i:s', $date);
```

Comment: my date format is 17 Nov, 2015 09:00 but it dosn't convert into strtotime