# String to datatime

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert this string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063057/convert-this-string-to-datetime)

I have to convert my string value into datetime.Is there any php function which can convert varchar value into datatime.my value are coming like this:

```
$a= "2013-Jan-12-(Sat) 03:30 PM";
```

and i want to convert it simple datetime. Like: 2013-1-12 15:30:45

Comment: Look at PHP DateTime objects

Comment: Have u ever used strtotime() function?

Comment: yes i have tried it but it does not convert the date into right datetime.

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-M-d-(D) H:i A", $a);`

Comment: Using the term "datetime" is likely to get people confused because that's the name of a mySQL field type. Just say "date and time". Shiplu's answer is the correct one.

Comment: but this is not working for me.

Comment: What *exactly* is not working for you how? What result are you getting? Remember that to show a `DateTime` date, you need to use `format()`. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be the sat is the problem try to change that or add that at first, you may get it.

Answer (score 0):

$Date = new DateTime("13-Jan-12-(Sat) 03:30 PM")

should do the trick. if thats not working, look at strtotime.

Comment: If it's not working, look at the DateTime createfromformat() method, not revert to strtotime