# String to Datetime in php?

Tags: php, string, datetime

I am getting a text `datetime` by `explode()` function. Like this.

```
$date = "26 July 2014";
```

I want to convert it to `datetime` and i can do substractions.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about the result you need, what have you tried etc.?

Comment: Try `strtotime` function

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063057/convert-this-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s    = "26 July 2014";
$date = strtotime($s); //1406347200
echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $date); //07-26-2014 00:00:00
```

For Subtracting:

```
$newdate = strtotime ( '-2 day' , strtotime ( $s ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
echo $newdate; //2014-07-24
```

Answer (score 0):

@Leerner answer is good but if you want to create DateTime object you can use

```
$dateTimeObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y', '26 July 2014');
```

or

```
$dateTimeObj = date_create_from_format('d F Y', '26 July 2014');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

to substract you can use [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) or [sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) method

```
$dateTimeObj->modify('-1 day');
echo $dateTimeObj->format('d F Y');
```

or `date_modify()` function

You can check how this work [on this fiddle](http://ideone.com/kJQwUH)