# String to Datetime in Php

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I get a date value from the port. And I want to convert that string value to datetime. But I couldn't figure out how. Deletes 0 at the beginning of the code the way I tried.

Incoming value:

```
;03122019;164202;
```

My code:

```
$data = fread($socket, 1024);
$down= array();
$down= split("#",$data);
$list_n= split(";",$down[$i]);
$time = '';
$time = strval($list_n[1])+''.$list_n[2];
$newformat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);
echo "Time ---------------> ".$time;
echo $newformat;
```

Result:

```
Time ---------------> 3122019164202
 3122-01-19 23:01:57
```

Deleting the initial 0. I want to edit these values and insert them into the database.

I want:

```
Time ---------------> 2019-12-03 16:42:02
```

Comment: i think you need to echo the $newformat not the $time

Comment: I tried it. But result :  '3122-01-19 23:01:57' @rrsantos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert uncommon date format to timestamp in most efficient manner possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843423/convert-uncommon-date-format-to-timestamp-in-most-efficient-manner-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dateTime = str_replace(";","",";03122019;164202;");
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYHis', $dateTime);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Update: thank for [@Nemoden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485676/nemoden)'s suggest, you can use createFromFormat without the `str_replace()`

```
$dateTime = ";03122019;164202;";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(';dmY;His;', $dateTime);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2019-12-03 16:42:02
```

Comment: beat me to this... :) but my improvement over the code is that you can actually leave those `;` in the format, so there is not need to `str_replace` anything

Comment: Deleted my answer. The only difference is absence of `str_replace`, but the format of `DateTime::createFromFormat` is `';dmY;His;`

Comment: if you could illustrate that, that'd be great :)